# How can I configure Apache to point `http://*.dev` to `/path/to/sites/*/html` using VirtualDocumentRoot?

Tags: apache

I'm using `dnsmasq` to point `http://{anydir}.dev` to `/path/to/sites/{anydir}`.

Here's the `vhosts.conf` snippet necessary to make this work:

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
  ServerName dev
  ServerAlias *.dev

  VirtualDocumentRoot /path/to/sites/%-2+
</VirtualHost>
```

This works great for html directories that live at the root level. But what if all of my html files live in an html directory?

All of my web files live in a directory like this:

```
/path/to/sites/site1/html/index.html
/path/to/sites/site2/html/foo.html
```

This doesn't work: `VirtualDocumentRoot /path/to/sites/%-2+/html`

How can I point `http://*.dev` to `/path/to/sites/*/html`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a somewhat wild guess, since I didn't setup an example to test this. But according to the documentation this should work:

```
VirtualDocumentRoot "/path/to/sites/%-2+/html"
```

Note the quotes around the path... not really sure why this actually is required (or better when), it seems to depend on your environment...